# Library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-AFNetworking

Tags: xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have some strange error that I am having trouble with. For the record, every framework in my project is added via Pods. I had `AFNetworking` in my project. My project actually does not use `AFNetworking`, it is using one framework for SOAP messages. I've uninstalled `AFNetworking` via Pods. I have removed `DerivedData` folder. I have updated my Pods with `pod update` command. I do NOT have `AFNetworking` framework in my project. Everything is ok, except title mentioned error. I've tried to remove lPods.a. There is none in my project folder structure, I've checked. I've tried to remove Pods with `rm -rf Pods` and installing everything again. Nothing. Again this error pops up every time when I try to build my solution.

And yes, if anyone asks I'm opening .xcworkspace, not .xcodeproj. 
Those anyone has a clue what else to try ?

EDIT: I've tried to remove `-l"Pods-ProjectName-AFNetworking”` From Other linker flags and `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking"` from Header search paths. Now it gives me the same error for ReactiveCocoa.

Comment: check your Pods-PlacesAutoComplete.debug.xcconfig and Pods-PlacesAutoComplete.release.xcconfig files, whether they contains afnetworking references

Comment: There are none AFNetworking references there. There are ReactiveCocoa references but I still get error for ReactiveCocoa if I do what I did for AFNetworking in Other linker and Header search paths.

Comment: search for afnetworking in the workspace

Comment: No results for AFNetworking in workspace. It's funny for ReactiveCocoa error because I have that in workspace and everything.

Comment: try by quitting Xcode then run pod install command again

Comment: I've done pod install. I've removed Pods directory and re/install everything again. I've updated Pods. Nothing. Every time the same thing happens.

Comment: can you post the screenshot?

Comment: Also check whether in you build phases>linked binary is showing any libs

Comment: I cannot add a screenshot I am afraid but it says ld: library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-LinqToObjectiveC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). It's in red and it shows libPods-ProjectName.a in red. I've already tried to delete that, nothing.

Comment: adter removing libPods-ProjectName.a  run pod install

Comment: I've tried and it creates it again in Linked binary and it is red again (libPods-ProjectName.a)

Comment: one libPods-ProjectName.a should be there... even after pod install showing lib not found error?

Comment: search AFNetworking in build settings and make sure there is no reference in framework search path also

Comment: There are none now. But the problem is, error propagates to ReactiveCocoa, and I'm using it in my project. Now it says ld: library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-ReactiveCocoa clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). And I have that framework installed and everything.